# How we define Fourier number for a sphere?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

> What is the Fourier number for a sphere with radius $R$ which is exposed to a surface temperature of $T_s$ for the period of $t$ seconds. Properties of sphere ($\rho, k, c_p$) are constant.

Comment: How does r change if you halve the volume of a sphere

Comment: Its straightforward if we use $m=\rho V$.

Comment: If the imposed surface temperatures on the two spheres is the same, than equality of the Fourier numbers is the correct approach.  Now, how are the mass and radius of a sphere related?

Comment: Thank you very much sir. We can relate mass and radius using $m=\rho V$. Can you explain how Fourier numbers are equal when imposed Temperatures are same?

Comment: If you properly reduce the transient heat conduction equation for a sphere to dimensionless form, you will see immediately that the Fourier numbers will have to be the same.  Do you know how to do that?  You should have been taught that.  What is the volume of a sphere in terms of its radius?

Comment: I will try to derive the dimensionless form and see if I can conclude the desired equality of Fourier numbers. Finally we should use $V=\frac{4}{3} \pi r^3$.

Comment: So, what is the algebraic relationship between r and m?

Comment: Its $m=\frac{4}{3} \pi \rho r^3$. I don't have problems with this part sir :)

Comment: I would be happy if you explain the dimensionless forms. I can't get the result :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transient Heat Conduction equation for a sphere:
$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=\alpha\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}\right)$$
Boundary conditions:
$$T=T_s\tag{r=R}$$
$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}=0\tag{r=0}$$
Initial conditions:$$T=T_0\tag{t=0}$$
Define the following dimensionless variables:
$$\theta=\frac{T-T_0}{T_s-T_0}$$
$$\xi=r/R$$
$$\tau=\frac{\alpha t}{R^2}=Fourier\ Number$$
Substitute dimensionless variables into differential equation and boundary conditions:
$$\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \tau}=\frac{1}{\xi^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}\left(\xi^2\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \xi}\right)$$
           $\theta=1$   @    $\xi=1$

$\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial \xi}=0$ @ $\xi=0$

$\theta=0$ @ $\tau=0$

So, $\theta$ is a function only of $\tau$ and $\xi$ (and the average temperature is a function only of the Fourier number $\tau$).